# Create Smaller XML based on value of element

Tags: lxml, elementtree

On Python 3.7, I am looking to create a subset of a XML. For example, the larger XML is:

```
    <data>
        <student>
            <result>
                <grade>A</grade>
            </result>
            <details>
                <name>John</name>
                <id>100</id>
                <age>16</age>
                <email>john@mail.com</email>
            </details>
        </student>
        <student>
            <result>
                <grade>B</grade>
            </result>
            <details>
                <name>Alice</name>
                <id>101</id>
                <age>17</age>
                <email>alice@mail.com</email>
            </details>
        </student>
        <student>
            <result>
                <grade>F</grade>
            </result>
            <details>
                <name>Bob</name>
                <id>102</id>
                <age>16</age>
                <email>bob@mail.com</email>
            </details>
        </student>
        <student>
            <result>
                <grade>A</grade>
            </result>
            <details>
                <name>Hannah</name>
                <id>103</id>
                <age>17</age>
                <email>hannah@mail.com</email>
            </details>
        </student>
    </data>
```

and am looking for a new XML like below, the condition to create a smaller subset depends on a list of ids in this case 101 and 102. All other student blocks will be deleted.

```
    <data>
        <student>
            <result>
                <grade>B</grade>
            </result>
            <details>
                <name>Alice</name>
                <id>101</id>
                <age>17</age>
                <email>alice@mail.com</email>
            </details>
        </student>
        <student>
            <result>
                <grade>F</grade>
            </result>
            <details>
                <name>Bob</name>
                <id>102</id>
                <age>16</age>
                <email>bob@mail.com</email>
            </details>
        </student>
    </data>
```

i.e. The output XML will depend on a list of id's, in this case ['101',102']

This is what I tried:

```
    import lxml.etree
    #Original Large XML
    tree = etree.parse(open('students.xml'))
    root = tree.getroot()

    results = root.findall('student')
    textnumbers = [r.find('details/id').text for r in results]
    print(textnumbers)

    required_ids = ['101','102']

    wanted = tree.xpath("//student/details/[not(@id in required_ids)]")
    for node in unwanted:
        node.getparent().remove(node)

    #New Smaller XML    
    tree.write(open('student_output.xml', 'wb'))
```

But I am getting an expected error of "Invalid expression" for

```
wanted = tree.xpath("//student/details/[not(@id in required_ids)]")
```

I know it's a read, but i am fairly new to Python, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

required_ids = ['101','102']

for event, element in ET.iterparse('students.xml'):
    if element.tag == 'student' and not(element.xpath('.//id/text()')[0] in required_ids):
        element.clear()
        element.getparent().remove(element)
    if element.tag == 'data':
        ET.dump(element)
```

Instead of the `dump` you would of course want to write to a file, that is use

```
    if element.tag == 'data':
        tree = ET.ElementTree(element)
        tree.write('student_output.xml')
```

Your attempt fails as you can't simply use a Python list variable in XPath and `in` is not an XPath 1.0 operator.

Comment: Thanks Martin.. I got the answer but to write to file neither tree.write('student_output.xml') nor ET.write('student_output.xml') is working. tree.write gives me the original XML and ET.write throws an error "AttributeError: module 'lxml.etree' has no attribute 'write'"

Comment: @Rajat, I have added code how to write to a file instead of simply "dumping" the result, both the "dump" as well as that code produce the filtered XML for me.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have a updated version of the problem on the below link. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/57966419/11959772