# Modify large file containing multiple XML files to create small file depending on condition

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, elementtree

I have a large file that contains multiple XMLs in different lines. I want to create a new file with lines (or XMLs) depending on a condition where multiple tags match columns of spreadsheet. For example, I have a large XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><student><result><grade>A</grade></result><details><name>John</name><house>Red</house><id>100</id><age>16</age><email>john@mail.com</email></details></student></data>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><student><result><grade>B</grade></result><details><name>Alice</name><house>Blue</house><id>101</id><age>17</age><email>alice@mail.com</email></details></student></data>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><student><result><grade>F</grade></result><details><name>Bob</name><house>Blue</house><id>100</id><age>16</age><email>bob@mail.com</email></details></student></data>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><student><result><grade>A</grade></result><details><name>Hannah</name><house>Blue</house><id>103</id><age>17</age><email>hannah@mail.com</email></details></student></data>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><student><result><grade>C</grade></result><details><name>James</name><house>Red</house><id>101</id><age>18</age><email>james@mail.com</email></details></student></data>
```

I need to create a file where the house and id are picked from a xlsx file like below:

[image]

and create a new file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><student><result><grade>F</grade></result><details><name>Bob</name><house>Blue</house><id>100</id><age>16</age><email>bob@mail.com</email></details></student></data>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><student><result><grade>A</grade></result><details><name>Hannah</name><house>Blue</house><id>103</id><age>17</age><email>hannah@mail.com</email></details></student></data>
```

What I have tried:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(open('Student_data.xlsx','rb'),sheet_name="Sheet2")
df['House_Id']=df['House'].map(str)+'-'+df['Id'].map(str)
required_ids = df['House_Id'].tolist()
required_ids = [str(i) for i in required_ids]
for event, element in ET.iterparse('new_student.xml'):
    if element.tag == 'xml' and not(element.xpath('.//id/text()')[0] in required_ids):
        element.clear()
        element.getparent().remove(element)
    if element.tag == 'data':
        tree = ET.ElementTree(element)
        tree.write('student_output.xml')
```

I am able to create the required id using the 2 variables from the xlsx file (i.e. ['Blue-100', 'Blue-103']) but don't know how to:

1. Create a similar "pair-id" using the XMLs
2. Navigate to look for the "pair-id" and create a new file that contains only the required lines

Please let me know a way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to create a single result for all matched ids? Or one result file for each matched id?

Comment: I want to create a single result file that looks like the code snippet below the table above.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I was working on creating a list that has the tags and values like:
```
<house>Blue</house><id>100</id>
<house>Blue</house><id>103</id>
```
and just use this list to see if it present in every line. If yes then copy to new xml file.

Comment: Are you aware that any XML document can only have a single XML declaration and a single root element? So neither your input nor your wanted output is technically XML, it is a sequence of XML documents. You might be able to use XML API to parse or create a single XML document but parsing or creating line based sequences would have to happen on a file/readline/writeline based API or by string splitting/string joining.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you know the encoding given in the various XML declarations on each line is always UTF-8, then you can process the file with several lines where each line represents an XML document with file based IO and lxml etree as follows:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

required_ids = ['100','103']
required_houses = ['Blue', 'Blue']

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as w:
    for line in f.readlines():
        root = ET.fromstring(bytes(line, encoding = 'UTF-8'))
        if root.xpath('.//id/text()')[0] in required_ids and root.xpath('.//house/text()')[0] in required_houses:
            #ET.dump(root)
            print(ET.tostring(root, encoding = 'unicode'), file = w, end = '\n')
```